# How do you narrow types using a variable in a conditional in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The following doesn't compile:

```js
function returnString(): string {
  const s = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'hey' : null;
  const sIsString = s !== null;
  if (sIsString) {
    return s; // <-- problematic line
  }
  return 'hey';
}
```

Error: `Type '"hey" | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

It **does** compile when the comparison happens inside the conditional:

```js
function returnString(): string {
  const s = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'hey' : null;
  if (s !== null) {
    return s;
  }
  return 'hey';
}
```

Why does placing the type check inside a variable make a difference to the compiler?

Comment: You could replace `return s` with `return s!`, thus asserting that you are returning a non-null value. Or disable the `strictNullCheck` compiler flag. Looks like having this turned on makes the compiler unable to infer that returning value is always `hey` regardless of the branch. Both fixes are able to handle this. Let me know if this suits you as a possible answer.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, thanks for taking a look. I'm aware of those solutions, but I was hoping to find an explanation of why those workarounds are necessary in the first place. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone can explain why the compiler isn't able to infer the type assertion or if there's a less hacky solution.

Comment: No problem, I was not sure what your actual issue is. Fortunately, the answer provided below points to the compiler feature responsible for branch analysis that detects this `if ( s !== null ) return s` in contrast of `if ( whateverelse ) return s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism that can narrow down union type variables like `s` is called [control flow](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) [analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis), but it only happens on a per-variable basis.

The compiler cannot make a connection between your correlated variables `s` and `sIsString`. So if `sIsString` is `true`, you know that `s !== null`, but TS doesn't. It just looks at `s` and `sIsString`, as if they were completely independent.

The second case works, because you perform the type guard check directly on the variable `s` and as said control flow analysis works per variable. So its union type `string | null` can properly narrowed down to `string` after the `s !== null` type check.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issues (for "authoritative" or "canonical" answers to this): [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24865)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz!

Comment: Awesome, very helpful to know. Thanks @ford04 and @jcalz!